# Run a Spring batch as a scheduled task

Tags: spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I followed Spring [Batch processing example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) and wonder how it is possible to integrate it with another one, - [Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). There is a lot of magic happens here and there with all these annotations. How can I call the existing `BatchConfiguration` class to be able to read the same file every X time? In practice, of course, we'd like to fetch an external API instead. Thank you.

The source code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/belgoros/spring-batch-example).

Comment: The error I have is as follows: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner, .. Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobExecution: id=0`.

Comment: After just adding a component class annotated with `@EnableScheduling` and adding the method annotated with `Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)` to print to the log, it raised the above error :(

Comment: If I comment out the line `jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters())`an dleave just ` log.info("Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);` , the batch is exxecutes, then it writes to the log avery 5 secs.